# Is there a way to restart quicklookd on demand?

Tags: macos-catalina, quicklook

Whenever I update my QuickLook thumbnail/preview generator, I need to wait up to a minute for `quicklookd` to be automatically restarted before I can see the change.

```
$ qlmanage -m
...
generators change detected: quicklookd will restart soon
```

Is there a way to trigger `quicklookd` restart manually without having to wait for it to automatically restart?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `qlmanage -r` to manually reset Quick Look Server and all Quick Look client's generator cache.

Sometimes relaunching Finder (press `cmd` on **Finder > Relaunch**) also helps as you wont see immediate changes if the finder View hasn't changed and you just preview files.